# Удаление класса в самом классе

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Как в AS3 сделать, чтоб класс удалился сам в себе?

**Дополнено.**

```
package main 
{
    dynamic public class test
    {
        public function test() 
        {
        }
    dynamic    public function dest()
        {
            this = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот сам класс. В главном Main вызываю его. Точно можно в ActionScript3 такое делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this = null;

---

Из комментария:

Я не правильно посоветовал (перепроверил), Нужно так, используйте внутри класса

```
public static function deleteReference(reference:MyClass):void { reference = null; }
```

Comment: Не забудьте удалить все слушатели событий, сборщик мусора (garbage collector) не удаляет экземпляры c подписанными слушателями.

Comment: 1050: Нельзя выполнить присваивание неизвестной переменной.
говорит что не знает переменую this

Comment: Статический метод? Где вообще вызов происходит.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: Модификатор "dynamic" не используется с методами.

Comment: Я не правильно посоветовал  (перепроверил), Нужно так, используйте внутри класса

    public static function deleteReference(reference:MyClass):void
    {
        reference = null;
    }

Comment: что то не чего не получается
package main 
{
 
 
 public class test
 {
  
  var Str:String = "Hello";
  
  
  public function des() 
  {
   
   test.deleteReference(this);
   
   
  }
  
  public static function deleteReference(reference:test):void
   {
     reference = null;
  }
 
 }

}
компилит но не чего не удаляет проверял трэйсом

Answer (score 0):

Можно узнать, зачем это вообще нужно?

Создайте вспомогательный класс-фабрику с двумя статическими методами:
первый создает объект и помещает во внутренний статический контейнер.
второй удаляет объект из контейнера.
если больше нигде ссылки на объект не хранить, то объект будет удален.

если ссылаться на объект еще откуда-то, то можно организовать подсчет ссылок прямо в фабрике, по какому-нить идентификатору.

Но, вообще, странная идея. Как-то она не в духе концепции gc совершенно.

Comment: Ну мне было бы намного удобнее если объект можно было создать и забыть про него а когда он выполнил своё предназначения он само уничтожился

Comment: это достаточно просто организуется фабрикой+механизмом наследования.
И/или (возможно, еще проще) правильной реализацией IEventDispatcher